# Using recursion to draw a pattern of squares

Tags: python, recursion

So far this is the code I've written with the great help of my tutor.

```
def square(t, x, y, side):
    t.up()
    t.goto(x-side/2, y+side/2)
    t.down()
    for i in range(4):
        t.forward(side)
        t.right(90)

def squares(t, x, y, size, n):
    if n == 0:
        return
    if n >= 1: 
        square(t, x, y, size)

        half = size / 2
        squares(t, x - half, y + half, size / 2.2, n - 1)
        squares(t, x + half, y + half, size / 2.2, n - 1)
        squares(t, x + half, y - half, size / 2.2, n - 1)
        squares(t, x - half, y - half, size / 2.2, n - 1)


s = Screen()
t = Turtle()
t.pensize(2)
squares(t, 0, 0, 200, 3)
s.exitonclick()
```

So this program will draw a square with 4 squares on each point and 4 squares on each of their points. This was done within 1.5 hours of tutoring and my guy had to leave for family reasons and I couldn't finish this alone. Here is what the assignment wants.

[image]

So what I want is a square with a square with a square with a square

Comment: Code looks fine to me.  What happens when you run it? Is there an error or something you did not expect?

Comment: Sorry, we can not offer the service to guide you through your homework like a tutor does. This site is for *specific* programming questions. And you did not even ask one. But if you have a specific question, please edit your text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you got alot from your tutoring session...

just change

```
squares(t, 0, 0, 200, 3)
```

to

```
squares(t, 0, 0, 200, 5)
```